# What is the simplest way to implement multithreading in c# to existing code

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have already implemented a functionnal application that parses 26 pages of html all at once to produce an xml file with data contained on the web pages. I would need to implement a thread so that this method can work in the background without causing my app to seems unresponsive.

Secondly, I have another function that is decoupled from the first one which compares two xml files to produce a third one and then transform this third xml file to produce an html page using XSLT. This would have to be on a thread, where I can click Cancel to stop the thread whithout crashing the app.

What is the easiest best way to do this using WPF forms in VS 2010 ?

I have chosen to use the BackgroundWorker.

**BackgroundWorker implementation:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.LoadFiles();
        }

        private void btnCompare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                progressBar2.IsIndeterminate = true;
                // Start the asynchronous operation.
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            StatsProcessor proc = new StatsProcessor();
            if (lstStatsBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                if (lstStatsBox2.SelectedItem != null)
                    proc.CompareStats(lstStatsBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), lstStatsBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar2.IsIndeterminate = false;
            progressBar2.Value = 100;
        }
```

I have started with the bgworker solution, but it seems that the bw_DoWork method is never called when btnCompare is clicked, I must be doing something wrong... I am new to threads.

Comment: That's a very interesting user experience not being able to use a class because it's a grayed-out box.

Comment: Did either of the answers below (Background Worker or Tasks) help you?  If so, you should probably mark one as the 'answer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to threading I think the easiest to start with would be using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

- It uses another thread: You can asynchronously perform the HTML parsing while your app remains responsive
- It supports cancellation: You can can cancel the XML to HTML conversion

The BackgroundWorker is event-driven so it's much easier to get your ahead around if you're new to multi-threading. The .NET 4 Task library is much more flexible, but a little more involved to take advantage of especially with UI updates.

**Example:**

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((o, args) =>
{
    //Long running stuff here       
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    string result = "Hi UI!";
    args.Result = result;
});

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((o, args) =>
{
    if (args.Result != null)
    {
        SomeTextBox.Text = args.Result;
    }
});

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using .NET 4 and VS2010, I would use the Task Parallel Library.  Here's an example that shows the basics of how to background a task and marshal UI updates back to the GUI.  I think you need to use a BlockingCollection to implement the second part.

There is a good blog post that talks about chaining tasks and supporting cancellation:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx

Here's the example of back-grounding without a background worker

MainWindow.xaml - it's just a window with a status label.  The min necessary to get the point across:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="378" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="94" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Press Me</Button>
            <StatusBar>
                <Label Name="TheLabel" Content="Status" />
            </StatusBar>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Dispatchers are an easy way to update the UI from a background thread
        private System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher Dispatcher;

        // the Current Task - think of this as your background worker
        private Task CurrentTask;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // this line needs to run on the main thread.

            Dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        }

        private void UpdateStatus(string msg)
        {
            // marshall the call back to the main thread
            Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action( () => TheLabel.Content = msg ));
        }

        // we're going to calculate the average of a sh*tload (technical term) of numbers
        private void DoSomeWork()
        {
            // update the UI
            UpdateStatus("Doing Work");

            Random r = new Random();
            int max = r.Next(100000000, 1000000000);
            double avg = Enumerable.Range(0, max).Average();

            // update the UI
            UpdateStatus(string.Format("Done - Average = {0}", avg));
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // make sure the current task isn't already running
            if (CurrentTask != null && CurrentTask.IsCompleted == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wait");
                return;
            }

            // start a new one
            CurrentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    DoSomeWork();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do multithreading using [Threadpools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx).  However, the trouble and issues you will have everything to do with your code that produces this XML file.   If you restrict this code to only be running one thread at a time - but your UI still responsive, you will have less issues with your code.  (Instead of trying to run a thread and process multiple web pages at one time)